# Keyboard not working in ASUS Vivobook S 15 (2022) and Kubuntu 22.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-kernel, keyboard, asus

The keyboard on my ASUS Vivobook S 15 (2022) / Kubuntu 22.04 system
is not working. 
Only a select few functions keys are working, such as F4, F5, F6 and F7 (touchpad enable/disable, screen brightness controls, keyboard brightness and mic enable/disable). 
The touchpad is also working as intended. 
I have tried every possible solution that I could find
and I've resorted to using a USB keyboard.

I tried disabling `intel_vbtn` in `/etc/modprobe.d`,
upgrading and downgrading kernel, and adding keyboard in X11 config.

The keyboard works in BIOS and GRUB boot menu.

I have also tried using multiple OSes like:
Kubuntu 20.10, Ubuntu 20.10, Pop! OS, MX Linux, Linux Mint, Xubuntu
and Lubuntu.

Comment: Please give Fedora 36 a try, as it contains quite a fresh kernel (5.17). When testing distros, you need to realize it's generally not about the name, it's about the kernel version.

Comment: Were you able to solve this? I'm facing the same issue will test a distro with kernel later that 5.15 as is in kubuntu 22.04

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov, Same problem with Fedora 36 (Kernel 5.17). Next looking up to Kernel 5.19 on Manjaro which currently does not boot (UEFI boot menu keeps reappearing)

Comment: same issues with kernel 5.18/5.19 on debian sid.

Comment: This is a bit over my head, but does this help? https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=277260 (having the same issue)

Comment: Joost: If you have > 0 reputation, you have enough to post an answer.

Comment: Please refer to https://askubuntu.com/questions/1419702/vivibook-s14-oled-s3402-keyboard-not-detected/1426342#1426342. It might be related to your case as well.