# Keyboard on Asus Laptop (M3402RA) not working after plugging in external keyboard

Tags: linux, arch-linux, keyboard, asus

I have had this laptop (*Asus Vivobook S14 M3402RA*) for about a month now and I installed Linux on it without any major issues. However, a few days ago, when I plugged in an external keyboard, the laptop's built-in keyboard became unresponsive. I found that the keyboard was unresponsive even after unplugging the external one.

I tried reinstalling my system and I had high hopes as the keyboard worked in the BIOS menu. Unfortunately, this was not the case when the desktop environment loaded up. I tried this process with the following desktop environments (the keyboard did not function on either one): i3, hyprland, kde, gnome, lxde. I have tried a rolling-release distro (arch linux) and a stable one (linux mint) but the keyboard did not work on either.

I would like to note that the touchpad works everywhere, as do the Fn keys.

The problem is very similar to the one described in this post: [Keyboard not working in ASUS Vivobook S 15 (2022) and Kubuntu 22.04](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/709957/keyboard-not-working-in-asus-vivobook-s-15-2022-and-kubuntu-22-04)

I have also tried the solutions in this post, but they did not work: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1360683/keyboard-not-working-after-shutdown-asus-zenbook-13-oled-um325s/1363587#1363587

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It's difficult to know the exact problem without more information. Sharing the relevant contents of `/var/log/dmesg`, `/var/log/syslog` and the output of `lsusb` when the keyboard is plugged (it may be obtain via SSH from another host) may help identify the issue you have encountered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying out some different solutions, I managed to solve the problem in the following steps:

1. Booted into a Windows installer
2. Followed the instructions listed here (I installed all the drivers available for my device): https://www.asus.com/support/FAQ/1048624
3. Rebooted
4. Since I still could not connect to my WiFi network, I used an ethernet-to-usb-c adapter
5. Proceeded to successfully install Windows
6. Installed linux (tried both Ubuntu and Arch) and both distros worked flawlessly